# How to create a pixelate background in Photoshop CS6 to blend an image with the background

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

I need to blend this photo into a square shaped flyer and don't know what effect should i use on th background to make it look like the photo.

This is the photo

[image]

This is what i've done so far

[image]

I really like the "old" pixelated effect of the photo but i couldn't reproduce it in Photoshop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's film grain. You can try to reproduce it yourself or sample sections of the photo to create the rest of the background.

I recommend the second method because it's fast and relatively accurate.

Here's how:

1) Expand your canvas

2) Select the empty area plus some of the background (as shown in image)

3) Content-aware fill the area (shift + F5)

4) Fix it up a pit with cloning, spot-healing, or patching.

[image]

Here's my result:
[image]

You can see a lighter spot in the area above one of their heads, but this wouldn't be hard to clean up either.

Answer (score 1):

"pixelated effect of the photo" = film grain.

Easy to add in your photo editing software using a noise filter. Some editing software will even have a 'film grain' filter.

Comment: In Photoshop CS6 my problem is that if i add noise it adds black pixels instead of white pixels, i have set the secondary color to white and still have the same behaviour.

Comment: add noise to a new layer on top of your green. Use layer blending options and opacity to get it to match.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking out [this tutorial](http://psd.tutsplus.com/tutorials/photo-effects-tutorials/create-a-retro-urban-gig-poster-in-photoshop/). In a nutshell, it uses a cardboard texture and applies a multiply blend. You may need to experiment with different textures to match your image.